# Compressing data coming out of WCF

Tags: wcf, soap, compression, gzip

I would like to compress the data coming out of WCF on a basicHttpBinding.
I am trying to produce a new version of a system originally written as SOAP web services.  In that we returned a GZipStream when we received a request.

Is there any way to do the same with WCF?

I am using VS2010, currently against .Net 3.5 but that's flexible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to use IIS hosting and .NET 4.0 client you can use build in dynamic content compression in IIS. If client sends Accept-Encoding: gzip/deflate header to the service IIS will compresses the response for you. .NET 4.0 client is able to automatically decompress the response. Check [Support for HTTP Decompression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789.aspx) section.

Answer (score 1):

This page may help? It has a sample of a Compression Encoder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx